# How do I create code to handle errors in split(".")?

Tags: python, list, function, split

So i have this school task where i need to create code that handles errors like:
-Missing dots
-Several dots
-Dot as first and/or last character
-Empty string

I have the base as follows:

```
import random


def filesplitter_to_list(name : str) -> list:
    return  list(name.split("."))

name = input("Enter name:")

print(filesplitter_to_list(name))
```

That is the code i need to adapt to answer the errors correctly. It now prints the correct output when the input is correct like name = myfile.txt --> ['myfile', 'txt'].
But for example name = .myfiletxt. --> ['', 'myfiletxt', ''], when it should just print an empty list.

Sorry if I described this poorly. Ask if something is unclear

Any help from here?

Comment: So this function should only accept two words with a single dot between them (`file.txt`)? If so, you could check that the return value of `split` consists exactly of two elements and they both are not empty. That is your success condition. Return an error response otherwise.

Comment: I think the first thing you should do is work out what you want to happen for all of the error cases you can think of, so that you can then think through how the code could handle those cases.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that you can use

```
def filesplitter_to_list(name: str) -> list:
    parts = name.split(".")
    if name == "":
        return []
    if name[0] == "." or name[-1] == ".":
        return []
    if len(parts) != 2:
        return []
    return parts

name = input("Enter name:")
print(filesplitter_to_list(name))
```

Comment: This wors exactly like it should. Thank you!